# Undefined symbols for CMMotionManager

Tags: ios, symbols, cmmotionmanager

I have an older iOS project and am attempting to add core motion to it.  I get this error after adding this line:

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
```

error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:

I also got this error when including the i386 architecture.  I have now removed all architectures except arm6, but still get this error.

motionManager is declared here:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CMMotionManager * motionManager;
```

I have the CoreMotion framework included.

[image: Here are my architecture settings]

Comment: No, previously it was ios5+, but now I have it set to iOS 8.1 only.  Still get the same error.